# How can I highlight only the contents that have been never published yet in the Views?

Tags: views, 6, nodes

The contents always need approval of administer to be published on this site.

For example,
The contents are once unpublished by Rule module when non-adimin users update them.
And then the administer publish those contents again.

I have a node View with table style.
In this view the administer wants to find "The contents that have never been published yet" easily for example, by making them hi-lighted.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The published (actually status) field is just a toggle, 0 for unpublished, 1 for published.  There is no history of if a node has been published and then unpublished, so, there is no way to use it to find "contents that have never been published yet."  To do that, you would need to create another field in your content and set it upon the first publishing of the node.  Provided, of course, that that is your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Creating another field is a great idea. What type type of field would you use then ?

Comment: A simple text field that would be set to 'yes' upon the node's first publishing would probably suffice. You could set this field's default value to be 'no,' but realize that adding this field to the content type doesn't populate that value into existing nodes, so it would be best to check against 'yes' versus for 'no.'

Answer (score 0):

To display unpublished  content using views you  have to add "Node: Published" option as "No" under "Filters".

Comment: Thanks. But it was not my question..